# Typo in Apostol's Calculus?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I think there is a typo in this credible book. Or I get the exercise wrong.

> Apostol's *Calculus vol.1*, **Exercise 1.15-10** (page 70): Given a positive integer $p$. A step function $s$ is defined on the interval $[0, p]$
>   as follows: $s(x) = (-1)^nn$ if $x$ lies in the interval $n \le x < n + 1$
>   , where $n = 0, 1, 2, ..., p-1$; $s(p) = 0$. Let f(p) = $\int_0^p s(x) dx$
>
> a) Calculate f(4)

My answer is $-2$, but in the answers I found $-1$. As I understand this step function has values $0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6$ and so on. Then $(0 - 1 + 2 - 3) = -2.$

Comment: Yes it's probably a typo

Comment: There are several typos in the *answers to exercise*, but the rest of the book is pretty solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo: you're summing up the areas of 4 rectangles of width one, the first of which has height zero.

$p(4) = \Sigma_{i=0}^3 \int_i^{i+1} s \, dx = 0 - 1 + 2 - 3 = -2.$